# Shift + Enter no longer adds a new line in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I installed the Visual Studio 2010 productivity power tools, and since then Shift + Enter does not add a new line in the text editor. I've tried disabling all of the productivity tools settings and even uninstalling the productivity power tools entirely, but Shift + Enter still does nothing. I can't find the setting for this.

How can I re-enable shift + enter to add a space (just like enter alone does)?

Comment: Note that installing the VS power tools will do this when brace complete is enabled.

Comment: Why would you want shift-enter to act just like enter alone?  I find it much more useful for shift-enter to 1) add semicolon to current line, 2) insert new line below, 3) move cursor to new line below.  VS2010 productivity tools did this, but nothing for VS2012 so far...

Comment: Carl G: As someone who's forced to use multiple IDEs for various reasons at his day job, extremely minor typing 'shortcuts' (replacing two keys with two keys?) like that do me far more harm than good -- I can't rely on them being there for all my IDEs, and they interfere with my existing muscle memory.  For example, I found out I don't release shift very fast when creating new namespaces.  More often than not, after I installed powertools, I was left without a single newline when I spam this out: "namespace Foo <ENTER> { <ENTER> } <ENTER> <UP> <CTRL+ENTER>".

Answer (score 54, accepted):

- Go to `Tools/Options/Environment/Keyboard`.
- Switch the "Use new shortcut in:" dropdown to "Text Editor".
- Pick the `Edit.BreakLine` command.
- In the `Press shortcut keys` edit pane press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: apologies. I was slowed down by visual studio crashing when I tried to work out which command it was.

Comment: @TZHX: VS10? Ugh. You'd think that, after 10 versions, they got better at it. Anyway, I only now discovered that this was a VS10 question. I copied the steps from my VS9...

Comment: To be fair to them though - my system is a bit naff. But they haven't changed the core of their options/settings thing in 2010 I know.

Comment: +1 Amazing! Did not even think to try this, no idea it was even fixable. Cheers.

Comment: This worked for me, but only when I changed the "Use new shortcut in:" dropdown from "Global" to "Text Editor"

Comment: @Daniel; Indeed, I forgot to mention that! I'll add it.

Answer (score 8):

From Options menu, select "Environment", then "Keyboard" that gives you the option of setting keyboard shortcuts. The one you want should be "Edit.BreakLine" - you can search for them. Selecting this, you can then add/remove assosciated shortcuts.

Comment: Coming >10mins after the question was asked, you beat me by 21secs! `+1` from me.

Answer (score 4):

In new versions it was changed to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, And you easily can change it as [sbi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/140719/sbi) suggested

Answer (score 3):

Try Ctrl + Shift + Enter to add a line bellow.

Ctrl + Enter will add a line above.