# How to insert a new line while cursor is in between current line?

Tags: visual-studio

On VS2010, I have created a very simple marco that do:

1. Hit "End" key
2. Hit "Enter" key

Then bind it to Shift+Enter. So that even if I'm in between a line, I can easily insert a new line under and place the cursor at the beginning of the new line.

Now that marcos are gone in VS2012, I wonder how can I achieve the same job?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a shortcut to link `Edit.LineOpenBelow` and assign the keyboard command to <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 13):

`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` would do the work.

Possibly a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27098347/6061609).

Comment: And on Mac it's `⌘CMD + Shift + Enter`

Comment: In case someone changed this shortcut, it's the `Edit.LineOpenBelow` command in Keyboard settings.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need no macro for that (when I understand your question corretly).

Hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will add a new line **below** the current line and place the cursor at the beginning of the new line.

Hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will add a new line **above** the current line.

***NOTE:*** This does work at least in my Visual Studio 2012 installation, but I´m currently unsure if this functionality is provided by an installed extension

Comment: Currently "Shift+Enter" is not working on my machine. Do you know which command it bind to?

Comment: @sun1991 Shift+Enter is bound to `Edit.BreakLine` (FileCompare) and `Tools.AddEndTokenAtTheEnd` (TextEditor). Tools.AddEndTokenAtTheEnd is part of the `Productivity Power Tools`

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu :

sudo apt-get install xdotool

Settings >> keyboard >> add a custom shortcut

name : New_line

command : xdotool key End KP_Enter

then click the 'disabled' and type Right_shift key

Now you can use right shift to achieve what you want !

Comment: User is asking a question about Visual Studio, a PC/Mac exclusive software. This is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding **duplication** as well as **move** the current line in your repertoire:

| Action | Keyboard Chord |
| --- | --- |
| ⬆️ Line {**Insert**} Above | <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> |
| ⬆️ Line {**Move**} Up | <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>⬆️</kbd> |
| ️ Line {**Duplicate**} | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> |
| ⬇️ Line {**Move**} Down | <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>⬇️</kbd> |
| ⬇️ Line {**Insert**} Below | <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> |

Answer (score 0):

use (ctrl + enter) key in vs code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code, the command is **Insert Line Below** (settings name is `editor.action.insertLineAfter`) and the default key binding is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (Windows and Linux) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (Mac).

See [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_basic-editing) for this and other commands and their shortcuts.

Comment: this question is not about VS Code.

Comment: I know that, but I bet A LOT of people end up here looking for the answer in VS Code (as I did).