# How to add semicolon to the end of the line in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, but not working, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> start a new line, but not add semicolon at the end of previous line. Is there a shortcut?

Comment: You are hitting 2 keys anyway so why bother? `;` + `Enter` should work.

Comment: You can create a Shift+Enter keyboard shortcut using the freemium Visual Commander extension for Visual Studio.

Comment: It's a small thing, but when you're so used to not having to stretch for the right arrow or end keys in other editors it does slow you down a bit.For example, in Atom I installed the trailing-semicolon extension and added 'ctrl-shift-enter': 'trailing-semicolon:semicolon-newline' as a keyboard shortcut. WebStorm has this shortcut by default.

Comment: Due to incorrect question there are many confused commentators.
Shift + Enter in IntelliJ Idea not only sets semicolon, but sets all closing brackets, etc, i.e. everything it can to complete the current line of code.

Comment: for those thinking this is unneeded, textmate adds semicolon and goes to next line automatically with `cmd+return`, and it's useful :)

Comment: Why all these multi-key commands?  In prior IDEs, simply typing a semicolon adds the semicolon at the end of the line unless you're inside quotes, etc.  Smart Semicolon extension does this.

Answer (score 139):

Now there is an extension called [Colonize](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vmsynkov.colonize):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> Insert semicolon at the end of line and continue on the same line

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> Insert semicolon at the end of line and continue on the new line

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> Insert semicolon and stay at the same position

Comment: This doesn't work when Visual Studio Keymap extension is enabled.

Comment: However, if you go to keyboard shortcuts and set colonize and jump to newline as shift+enter. Now it works like is VS.

Comment: Not sure what is the use of this extension and shortcuts when they can be achieved with just `;` and `Enter`.

Comment: @SukumarRdjf in vs code, when you write a method call, it automatically closes the open parameter for you and your cursor ended up before the ).  Now if you want to write a new statement, you literally have to take your right hand off the jkl; position and click on the end or the right arrow key and then take your right hand back to the jkl; position to type the semicolon. I use shift + enter and it saves me around half a second for each statement to reposition my right hand

Comment: For Mac users replace Alt with option

option+Enter Insert semicolon at the end of the line and continue on the new line

control+option+Enter Insert semicolon and stay at the same position

Comment: If you want to change keyboard shortcut go to ```preferences>keyboard shortcuts```  and search clonoize, then you can edit shortcut there.

Answer (score 22):

Visual Studio Code doesn't appear to directly support adding a semi-colon to the end of a line via a keyboard shortcut, meaning it'll need a custom extension to support it.  Fortunately, Sergii Naumov has created one for us, named (appropriately) 'Trailing Semicolon'.

To install this extension:

1. Launch Visual Studio Code
2. Press "Ctrl+P" (or "Command+P" on the Mac)
3. type "ext install Trailing Semicolon" to search for the extension
4. With the extension visible below the search box, click the Install Extension icon in the bottom right of the extension. (It's a cloud with an arrow pointing down...)

You will need to restart Visual Studio Code to enable the extension (Visual Studio Code should prompt you to restart once the extension has been successfully downloaded.)

According to Sergii, the default keybinding for the extension is "cmd+;".  On my Mac, this meant pressing "Command+;", which worked great.

On my Windows 10 PC, I tried several key combinations ("Window+;" "Ctrl+;" "Alt+;" etc.), and nothing worked.  I opened the Keyboard Shortcut preferences (File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts) and searched for the new extension.  I found it listed at the end of the keybindings:

```
{ "key": "win+;",                 "command": "extension.trailing-semicolon",
                                  "when": "editorTextFocus" }
```

The "win" key binding apparently doesn't work.  I copied this binding to the keybindings.json file, changed "win+;" to "ctrl+;" and it worked like a charm!

Hope that helps.

Comment: perfect! the "windows+;" combination worked well OOTB on windows

Comment: Perfect! work in linux, kubuntu  18.04 KDE plasm.

Answer (score 18):

2021

> **settings** >search for **colon**
> You will find a javascript option to **insert** the semi-colon.

Answer (score 14):

I wrote an extension to mimic IntelliJ's complete statement.
Pressing `ctrl+;` (`cmd+;` on mac) appends `;` to the line end,
and moves cursor to line end.
If the line already ends with `;`, pressing `ctrl+;` just moves cursor to line end.

There is also experimental support for complete structures like `class`, `interface`, `function`, `if`, `switch`, `for`, and `while`. (Not understanding semantic of languages, so it may not work as you expected.)

You can install it as VSIX at [GitHub](https://github.com/weakish/vscode-complete-statement).

The version [vscode marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=weakish.complete-statement) is outdated. (Unfortunately my M$ account has been suspended, thus I cannot update it.)

Answer (score 9):

There is no way to do it by default that I could find. I just had to make do as best I could.

I ended up adding a binding via File>Preferences>Keyboard Shortcuts, and then pressing ; after the shortcut. Having the semicolon is part of the binding is as close as I could get... at least my finger is already over that key

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+;",
        "command": "cursorEnd",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }
]
```

This simply means that Ctrl+; brings you to the end of the line, and then tap ; again.

**Update (May 2021)**

Started using [VSCode Vim](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim) keybindings extension a few months ago. Highly recommend it. Out of interest, semi-colon end of the line is `A;` with vim keys⌨️

Comment: Used something similar in Sublime Text with Cmd+Space, but this is better in VS Code.  Works great.

Comment: If you're going to do this why not use CTRL-E (the default binding for cursorLineEnd) or CMD-Right Arrow (default for cursorEnd)?

Answer (score 8):

Try install the following ext then use shortcut: Ctr+; (Cmd+;)

[image]

Comment: this is really a good plugin, i have tested others and this one really works as expected

Answer (score 8):

**There is a way to have semicolon appended automatically by VSCode**.

By default this property is disabled:

1. For Windows `ctrl + ,`
2. For Mac `cmd + ,`

*Settings* -> *in Search bar type:* `'semicolon'` -> c*hange values to* `'insert'` *for both* **JS** *and* **TS**, *save and close*.

Now every time on save, VSCode will look for missing semicolons inside the file you're in and append them.

[image: Settings]

Answer (score 5):

I just started using Visual Studio Code and felt this requirement myself yesterday. After a quick google search I found this nice extension called "Prettier". Being a little new to VSCode it took me a few hours to get it all setup but it works like a charm now. Here are the steps and my setup. I hope it helps others.

**My coding environment**: VSCode running on a Windows 10 desktop environment connecting to my codebase SMB share hosted on my development machine which is running Ubuntu server 18.04.

**Solution Steps**

- Install `node` on the Windows desktop
- Run, `npm install -g prettier`
- Install the `Prettier` extension in VSCode
- Edit the `settings.json` file for VSCode and add the following

  ```
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
       "[javascript]": {
            "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
       }
      // Set the default
      "editor.formatOnSave": true
  ```
- Add the `.prettierrc` file at the root of my codebase on the ubuntu host (e.g.: `/var/www/html/tutorials`) with the following basic styling configuration

```
    {
      "semi": true,
      "trailingComma": "all",
      "singleQuote": true,
      "printWidth": 80
    }
```

- Restart VSCode and open the code file
- Use the existing VSCode keyboard shortcuts to apply formatting to the entire file `(Ctrl+K Ctrl+F)` or to a selection `(Shift+Alt+F)`
- Or simply saving the file `Ctrl+S` adds the formatting while saving the file with no additional work required
- Viola!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old post but Prettier - code formatter for vs code adds the semi colon (amongst other formatting).

```
ext install esbenp.prettier-vscode
```

Comment: It'll work only for *some* languages that Prettier supports.

Answer (score 1):

(March 2022) **Missing semi colons can be added automatically** without the needing of an extension (*with a little catch ;) They are added every time your code is formatted.

Go to settings: Look for this settings if you are writing javascript:
[image]

And/or go to settings: Look for this settings if you are writing typescript:
[image]Go to settings: Look for this settings if you are writing javascript:

Format your code and semi colons will be added \o/ Yeah

*The catch: As the settings says: Your workspace needs to have typescript 3.7 or newer.

Comment: I changed semicolon setting to insert, but after some times, it goes back to ignore. Is this setting not permanent,  or I missing something?

Comment: @ggsuha check if that setting scope is by project (workspace) or by user (all the projects). Also check that your settings are not stored in a repository like git, someone else could be changing that setting after a push.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl+Shift+P` and open Preferences:Open keyboard shortcuts (JSON) in VS Code

and insert

```
{
    "key": "tab",
    "command":"cursorEnd",
    "when":"editorTextFocus"
}
```

`tab` is optional, ofc. 
Put whatever you want from the keys on the keyboard.

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+P` does nothing on my vscode in mac (vscode has so many thousands of keyboard shortcuts and inconsistent behaviour and it's so customizable that the default behavior is terrible...) /rant

Answer (score 0):

If you need semicolons on Javascript/Typescript using vscode do:

**Settings**

type "semicolon"

you will have options for Javascript & Tyepscript

select the "insert" option as desired

You can also select semicolons for css, less, or scss

/*******/

You can select the "Show matching extensions" and get some extra help with extensions that address the same issue.

Comment: I did see the settings inside VSCode, enabled them putting "insert", and it still does nothing... would you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings: Look for this settings if you are writing javascript: enter image description here

And/or go to settings: Look for this settings if you are writing typescript: enter image description hereGo to settings: Look for this settings if you are writing javascript:

Format your code and semi colons will be added \o/ Yeah

*The catch: As the settings says: Your workspace needs to have typescript 3.7 or newer.

This solution works for me

Answer (score 0):

Add the following configuration in settings.json：

`"css.completion.completePropertyWithSemicolon": true`

or you can cancel by:

`"css.completion.completePropertyWithSemicolon": false`

other

```js
"scss.completion.completePropertyWithSemicolon": true,
"less.completion.completePropertyWithSemicolon": true
```

Answer (score 0):

### Add semicolon to the end of the line and go to the next line

##### Shortcode: `ctrl+;`

Install plugin: **multicomando**

`ext install ryuta46.multi-command`

Edit file: `keybindings.json`

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+;",
        "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
        "args": { 
            "sequence": [
                "cursorEnd",
                { "command": "type", "args": { "text": ";" } },
                "lineBreakInsert",
                "cursorDown"
            ]
        },
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }
]
```

- This plugin promotes a sequence of commands. Infinite possibilities!

##### I hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You can try Semicolon Insertion Shortcut.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It's in Visual Studio's Preferences. Solution from [sbi's answer here:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4317685/4416783)

> - Go to `Tools/Options/Environment/Keyboard`.
> - Switch the "Use new shortcut in:" dropdown to "Text Editor".
> - Pick the `Edit.BreakLine` command.
> - In the `Press shortcut keys` edit pane press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Worked for me!

Comment: Moti, just in case, you could remove your "answer" and probably it will removes downvotes from your account.