# Tab over last semicolon and parentheses

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been using Visual Studio Code for a short time. Is there a option to jump over the last semicolon and parentheses with tab?

Like when I type:

```
alert("hellof")
```

My cursor would be after the f and than I want to tab over the last semicolon and parentheses.

Comment: What semicolon?

Comment: Actually, I think you're looking for this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vmsynkov.colonize as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118344/how-to-add-semicolon-to-the-end-of-the-line-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 0):

As [Blorgbeard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369/blorgbeard) commented, the [Colonize](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vmsynkov.colonize) extension skips the rest of the characters in a line, appends a semicolon to the current line, and places the cursor on a new line when you press Alt + Enter.

If you specifically want the Tab key to do this, you may have to do some keymapping/macro-making or something else of that sort.