# Javascript semicolon Auto

Tags: javascript, node.js

Please can you help me add semicolon to my javascript project without adding it line by line i wan to add the javascript semicolon automatically i search for visual studio code and atom but i didn't find an extension please help

for ex :

```
exports.becomeSellerPost = async function(req, res) {
  let user = new User(null, null, req.session.user._id)
  user.becomeSeller().then(() => {
    req.flash('errors', 'Welcome Author')
    req.session.save(function() {
      res.redirect('/dashboard')
    })
  }).catch((err) => {
    req.flash('errors', "Somthing went wrong")
    req.session.save(function() {
      res.redirect('/')
    })
  })
}
```

to but automatic not manual

```
exports.becomeSellerPost = async function(req, res) {
  let user = new User(null, null, req.session.user._id);
  user.becomeSeller().then(() => {
    req.flash('errors', 'Welcome Author');
    req.session.save(function() {
      res.redirect('/dashboard');
    });
  }).catch((err) => {
    req.flash('errors', "Somthing went wrong");
    req.session.save(function() {
      res.redirect('/');
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: How are you attempting to achieve this?
This looks like an IDE feature and not language related. What is your IDE?

Comment: Visual Studio Code

Comment: I'd start by looking here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118344/how-to-add-semicolon-to-the-end-of-the-line-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 1):

3 years late to answer this question, but it may benefit future readers...

Visual Studio Code already comes built-in with this feature now which inserts semi-colon while 'formatting' the Javascript/Typescript code. You could enable it by choosing 'insert' from the settings like shown in the screenshot below -

[image: Set the value to 'insert' which auto-inserts semi-colon when 'formatting' the code.]

Comment: Good to know! I have provided a vim-based solution as well. stackoverflow is great, because, if the asker waits a bit, then answers start to pop in.

Answer (score 0):

If you use vim, then this is a solution:

```
:g/^.*[^\{\}]$/normal A;
```

Result:

[image]

Explanation: after `:g`, we have a pattern, that is: any line that does not end with `{` or `}`.

[image]

https://learnvim.irian.to/basics/the_global_command