# Is there a way to auto-format flutter with vscode?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I was wondering if there is a library like Eslint for Flutter/Dart that will automatically insert semicolons and trailing commas when I save the file.

FLutter Version: 1.22.3
Dart Version: 2.10.3

Answer (score 81, accepted):

With VS Code version 1.53 ( I am sure previous have this too) you don't need to install any special extension. Just navigate to:

Preferences -> Settings -> Text Editor -> Formatting

make sure "Format on save" is enabled

[image]

with every time you hit `Ctrl + S` your file will be saved as well as code formatted.

Comment: If this does not work for you, remember that you must change the file first before hitting `ctrl + S`. Otherwise the formatter will not run.

Answer (score 66):

1. install the `flutter` extension.
2. append or modify these lines in the `settings.json` file:

```
"[dart]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Dart-Code.dart-code",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
}
```

after this, you can format your dart file with the save (`ctrl+s`) action.

Comment: Of all the above prescription, this is what worked for me. Thanks a lot

Comment: This is the best option because it doesn't mess with your formatting in other languages. Wonderful

Comment: It seems to not work on VSC for mac  :(

Answer (score 22):

You can format every flutter file with one command like this...

```
 dart format . -l 120
```

It sets the line length I believe, which as a side effect formats all your code its brilliant

Comment: note this is being replaced - [!] The "format" command is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Flutter. Please use the "dart format"
sub-command instead, which takes all of the same command-line arguments as "flutter format".

Answer (score 11):

**Open VS Code settings**

- **File-> Preferences->Settings**

[image: Open VS Code settings]

**Text editor->Formatting**

[image: Format settings]

- **Enable Format on paste**
- **Enable Format on save**

Answer (score 8):

actually optional colons are what allow automatic formatting... I'm not sure it is really helpful to automatically have a colon or semicolon at the end of a line as it may varies and also I do not things there is an extension that effectively do that (except having some sort of other shortcuts)...

So although it does not answer exactly your question, it may help other users looking on how to format their flutter code: if you have all the optional colons the best way is to run the command included in the flutter plugin. From the terminal just run `flutter format lib` and it will format all the dart files in the lib directory and subdirectory. You can change `lib` with whatever directory you like.

Finally you could add some extension and activate few plugins to get a much readeable file. But that is a matter of personal appreciation. I personally use: `Bracket Pair Colorizer 2`, `Indent-Rainbow` and activate the two dart option for `flutter outline` to get this result :

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is a Code Formatting help area in the documentation.There is a section for VsCode [Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/formatting). It explains that

> To automatically format the code in the current source code window, right-click in the code window and select Format Document. You can add a keyboard shortcut to this VS Code Preferences.

After installing the Flutter extension.

I also found another Stack Overflow post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118344/how-to-add-semicolon-to-the-end-of-the-line-in-visual-studio-code)  that may be able to help you with a few extension suggestions and a way to make your own bindings for/in VsCode.

Comment: Instructions for setting up VSCode for Flutter development are [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor?tab=vscode)

Comment: @AdamKern good link as well. I simply wanted to link directly to the CodeFormatting section. These links should solve the issue I believe.

Comment: It shows the error of the missing semicolon, if you press "ctrl + ." it suggests that I insert a ";" but it won't auto-fix it on save like Eslint works on javascript..

Comment: @FabioDias I updated my answer to link to another SO post that has a few suggestions on how to configure VsCode to support the semicolon autocompletion you are wanting.

Comment: Seems like it's not possible to dart to be formatted as the Eslint does for javascript.

Answer (score 5):

you can use this command as mentioned in the official documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/formatting

`flutter format .`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `dart format .` to format all folder. Depcreated `flutter format .`

Also, you can install flutter vs code extension and enable format on save to format a particular file

Comment: Great command!!!

Answer (score 2):

In Extensions, search for [Prettier - Code formatter]

It formats your code once you click ctrl+S

Answer (score 1):

if this image appears without a bar from vs code
[bar vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzG5f.png)

go in Preferences -> Settings
and look for -> Default Formatter

[setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdTiD.png)
and change to Dart and you're done

Answer (score 1):

A simple shortcut for format the flutter code (Dart)

```
  Ctrl + ALT + L
```

Your code will be formatted.

Answer (score 0):

I was briefly on VSCode now back trying out Intellij but remember the hot key combination being:
ctrl + shift + i.  I could not tell if it was ctrl+shift+L or i but pretty sure it was i.  Also trailing commas helps the formatter do its job as the Flutter.dev documentation says.

Comment: it's ctrl-shift-i I just tried it

Answer (score 0):

On VS code for mac you can try this:

Go to ***Settings>Settings>***

[image]

Then ***Text Editor>Formatting***

[image]

Turn on Format on Save and you are done