# Strange formatting in VS Code using Dart / Flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Can I change this strange formatting?

[image: vscode screen]

Comment: Can you please share image that shows how end of file looks ?

Comment: I need at least 10 reputation to post images, but image you can see by click in link to imgur

Comment: Please check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64669962/is-there-a-way-to-auto-format-flutter-with-vscode

Comment: I just set "Dart: Line Length" from 80 to 120. Now formatting works good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of that format is that there's too much nested Widgets and there's a small screen space. A workaround for this is to expand the window/workspace then ["beautify" or format the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/how-do-you-format-code-in-visual-studio-code-vscode).

Updating the line length should also work. On VS Code, head to `Preferences > Settings > Extensions > Dart & Flutter` and change the value set on 'Dart: Line Length'. Typing 'line length' on the Settings search bar should also help you get to the config quicker.

[image: VS Code Settings]