# Is there a VSCode keyboard shortcut to auto format a class/method instance so that each parameter is indented and on a new line?

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut on VSCode to auto format the following code? Is it language-dependent? Using Dart for example:

```
class User {
  String id;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String email;
  String phoneNumber;
  String city;

  User({
    required this.id,
    required this.firstName,
    required this.lastName,
    required this.email,
    required this.phoneNumber,
    required this.city,
  });
}

// VSCode autocompletes this
var user = User(id: '', firstName: '', lastName: '', email: '', phoneNumber: '', city: '');

// But I want to format it into this
var user = User(
  id: '', 
  firstName: '', 
  lastName: '', 
  email: '', 
  phoneNumber: '', 
  city: ''
);
```

Comment: Open the Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift + P) and start typing "Format Document". You should see it there, along with its keyboard shortcut (Shift + Alt + F). Yes, formatters are language-dependent of course. The command might not be available if no formatter is installed for the currently-selected language.

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I don't think the formatter will enforce conventions such as splitting single-line statements into multiple lines. It just cleans up what you have.

Comment: I would enable [format on save](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66538607/3080848) if it isn't already. If you add a trailing comma `city: '',` the formatter will put each argument on its own line.

Comment: Dart formatting has only one setting: line width, default 80.  That's it.  Everything else is decided by the dart and flutter core teams.

Answer (score 0):

The Dart formatter currently formats calls like this differently depending on whether there is a trailing comma after the last argument:

```
foo(a);

foo(
  a,
);
```

There's some info about this at https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/formatting#using-trailing-commas.

There's an open proposal at https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/issues/1253 to change this behaviour to automatically add trailing commas during formatting (and formatting this way) which might make this simpler in the future.