# VS Code Flutter shortcuts equivalent to Android Studio Flutter

Tags: android-studio, visual-studio-code

I am looking for a few things to improve my productivity, Android Studio has these features and it really sped up my work, if you know any of these please share.

1. Ctrl+Shift+Space equivalent in VS Code Flutter. What it did in Android Studio was auto complete a statement. For example if I typed in `if` and then hit Ctrl+Shift+Space, the if condition code block would be completed for me automatically with `()` and `{}` after it, with putting the cursor within the condition.
2. Code snippets for things like for loops. On Android Studio you could type in `iter` and then Tab, it would create `for (var _ in ) {}` and automatically jump to both variables to fill their names on two Enter keystrokes.

These were great for me, please share if these exist in VS Code, as I understand it is supposed to be superior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install [dart](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.dart-code) extension for VSCode.

[image: dart extension if snippet]
[image]

In order to prioritize the extension snippets and have these ones for the first suggestion, go to `File/Settings/Text Editor/Suggestions` and set `Snippet Suggestions` to `top`. Now it looks like

[image]

Comment: It is installed, but I have always used the first if and for! I didn't notice there were two, thank you. Is there a way to remove the redundant first if and for suggestions?

Comment: Yeah it's possible, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, is it also possible to add a semicolon automatically to the end of a code block or line while typing? In Android Studio Ctrl+Shift+Enter also does that.

Comment: @Jiehfeng Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39466883/12696223